# Can I parallelize long running task in queue without creating too much threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread pool with queue for 250 entries and every second I am pushing every second 60 tasks. Normally a task runs very fast, but if some condition will meet, a long running task is necessary. The normal task run is now blocked, because the long running task is now being executed. Is it possible to split the execution for one Runnable (in the case the long running task is needed) in execution time for

1. the normal task
2. the long running task

?

In other words: I like to start the long running task asynchronously, but I do not want to create too much threads, because I that case I would get an overhead because of the thread communication. Can I use a ForkJoinPool for this or do I have to separate the long and short running task to solve this?

My machine has 4 cores:

```
ExecutorService queue = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2,
            4,
            400,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(250, true),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy());
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
               if(isTimeForLongRunningExecution()){
                    //Is it possible to start this job asynchronous without starting to many threads
                    doLongRunningTask();
                }//do job with old data until new data is available, but do not block this operation too long
                doNormalTaskWithOldOrNewData();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void doNormalTaskWithOldOrNewData() throws InterruptedException {
            if(checkNewDataAvailable()){
               System.out.println("Work with new Data");
               Thread.sleep(300L);
               System.out.println("Work completed!");
            }else{ 
              System.out.println("Work with old Data");
              Thread.sleep(300L);
              System.out.println("Work completed!");
            }
        }

        private void doLongRunningTask() throws InterruptedException {
              System.out.println("Create new Data");
              Thread.sleep(3*60*1000L);
              System.out.println("Data creation completed!");
        }
    };//end of runnable

    while(true){
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            queue.submit(r);
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted?  Is it not working?  What behavior is it showing that you don't want?

Comment: As an aside, your code will only fork a 3rd thread when 250 jobs get queued.  Also, do you really want to use `DiscardOldestPolicy()` and drop tasks if you queue is full?

Comment: Do you need to wait the LongRunningTask to complete or can't you just wrap it up in a new Thread?

Comment: Also, what is the implementation of "checkNewDataAvailable" the application might slow down in there...don't know

Comment: The problem is that I have 4 cores and if no long running task is executed, I can use the power of the thread pool without blocking the queue. But if the long running task is executed, I need a possibility to run it in a asynchronous way. Creating an additional thread for each long running task would create to many threads and so I will get more threads than cores. (in my case: 60 additional threads). I will use the solution with the thread pools.

Comment: the long running task is creating some data, the short running task is working with. If the creation of the data is not finished yet, the short running task is working with the old data. The method "checkNewDataAvailable" is checking if this data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that comes to my mind is to use two queues. One bounded for the short-living tasks, and one unbounded for the long-living tasks.

You can as well construct the Executor with your own Thread-creation routine and make sure that all those long-living threads run at low priority, so they do not interfere with the short-living tasks.

```
final Executor longLivingTasksExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new PriorityThreadFactory(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY));
```

Where the `PriorityThreadFactory` is a class that I wrote myself:

```
public class PriorityThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory, ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {

  protected final ThreadGroup allThreads;
  protected final int priority;

  public PriorityThreadFactory(final String name, final int priority, final boolean daemon) {
    this.priority = priority;
    this.allThreads = new ThreadGroup(name);
    this.allThreads.setMaxPriority(priority);
    this.allThreads.setDaemon(daemon);
  }

  public PriorityThreadFactory(final int priority, final boolean daemon) {
    this("workers", priority, daemon);
  }

  public PriorityThreadFactory(final int priority) {
    this("workers", priority, false);
  }

  @Override
  public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
    return new Thread(this.allThreads, r);
  }

  @Override
  public ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(final ForkJoinPool pool) {
    final ForkJoinWorkerThread result = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
    result.setPriority(priority);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use it like you described, my queue will use 2-4 Threads and the longLivingTasksExecutor will use 1-2 Threads. Is this true? Can I also maximize the number of threads for the longLivingTasksExecutor to avoid the problem with too many threads?

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting task, however I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. You are giving a solution, but you are not telling us what the problem is, as there are many people here that could suggest you a more appropriate solution.

Anyway I would suggest you to download and use [**VisualVM**](http://visualvm.java.net/).

if you are not already using it, to monitor the performance and see where the delays are. In the past I found it very useful to understand where the threads are waiting (do you have synchronized code?).

Why don't you try to start the long running task in a separate Thread from the Normal task?
Also take a look at the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` as this is quite good to execute many [short-lived asynchronous tasks](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-executor-service-types).

Finally, if you are not already doing it, I'd also suggest to time the performance and see yourself how that improves/get worse, or use some other metrics (store somewhere the number of times the Normal thread reads New Data, Old Data).

Answer (score 0):

Use 2  [ordinary thread pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) - one for fast and another for long running tasks. Let each thread pool have as many threads as you have processor cores. Submit all tasks to the fast thread pool. Let task, if it sees that a long work is required, submits another task to the long thread pool and exit.